# Class tag automation on form_for? What is the best practice for this syntax?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I was on developing Rails App with bootstrap CSS, depends on the DRY concept, can this form be simplified?

```
<%= form_for @user , :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
<fieldset>
<legend>Sign Up</legend>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email ,:class=>"control-label" %><br />

    <%= f.text_field :email, :class =>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Email" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password ,:class=>"control-label" %><br />

    <%= f.password_field :password, :class =>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Password" %>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation,:class=>"control-label" %><br/>

    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation , :class =>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Confirm Password" %>

  </div>
<%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

I mean like the tag `fieldset` , `legend`, the `:class=>"control-label"` and the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [custom form builder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html). The basic point is to encapsulate field decoration (and even labeling, in many cases), so that you get similar output to your code above, with something like this:

```
<%= form_for @user, builder: MyFormBuilder do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

There are [many tutorials on how to build your own](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails%20custom%20form%20builde#q=rails%20custom%20form%20builder), it can be extremely handy and it is a great way to learn more. If you want a prepared solution, have a look at [the simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).